# How do I make material-ui progress bar update with large number of web socket messages causing render to happen often

Tags: reactjs, websocket, material-ui, state, render

I am using React and material-ui. I have a web socket delivering 9000 messages per minute.

In my react app, I have a material-ui determinate progress bar that gets its value from the web socket messages. The progress bar does not accurately reflect the values coming in from the web socket messages.

I am storing the web socket messages in state, so the UI is re-rendering often.

How to avoid this problem? I can't throttle the messages, as I need all messages saved and processed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't trottle the messages you can throttle the state updates instead. Please share the relevant code you have so far. Or you may be able to send the messages batched rather than each one individually. 150 messages/sec seems very much.

Comment: How would you throttle state updates? Perhaps you mean throttling the method that calls setState(). That might help, thanks.

Comment: I outlined a solution in my answer. It might need to be adjusted to your specific problem but it basically involves storing the messages in a `ref` and throttling the function that calls `setState()` with the current messages from the `ref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to throttle your state updates instead. A solution using [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) could look something like this:

```
const TOTAL = 100000;

const ProgressBar = ({socket}) => {
    const cache = useRef([]);
    const [messages, onMessage] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const update = throttle(() => onMessage(cache.current), 500);

        const handleMessage = message => {
            cache.current = [...cache.current, message];
            update();
        }

        socket.on('message', handleMessage);

        return () => {
            update.cancel();
            socket.off('message', handleMessage);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={messages.length / TOTAL} />
    );
};
```

Comment: I ended up storing all the data and using setInterval() to set the state every 100ms.